# Mini slider my own, stop on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I did slider on my own, because I couldnt find simple enough slider for my need.
It fits perfectly for me, just need one option more 
Stop setintreval on hover

**RECREATED EXAMPLE HERE** : [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/pBaDf)

```
  $("#sliderWrapper .arrow").click(function(){
   $( "#slider li" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" )
})

setInterval(function(){
   $( "#slider li" ).fadeToggle( "2500", "easeInOutExpo" )
}, 8000);
```

any help would be appreciate, Thank You :)

Comment: cmon, no one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way of i can think of would be to use jQuery's `:hover` selector, as follows;

```
setInterval(function(){
  $( "#slider:not(:hover) li" ).fadeToggle( "2500", "easeInOutExpo" )
}, 8000);
```